# Error to load shp file: GDAL Error 4: Failed to read GeoJSON data

Tags: r

I have problems to load a shp file. This is my code

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE,warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)

install.packages("geojsonio")
library(geojsonio)
library(rio)
library(gridExtra)
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
library(JLutils) # devtools::install_github("larmarange/JLutils")
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)
library(sf)
library(ggrepel)
library(readxl)
library(plyr)
library(cowplot)
library(ggpubr)
install.packages("directlabels")
library(directlabels)
data <- rio::import("https://github.com/jincio/COVID_19_PERU/blob/master/docs/reportes_minsa.xlsx?raw=true")


knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE,warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)

When I run I try to create deparamento , I get this error message:
```

Error: Cannot open "https://github.com/jincio/COVID_19_PERU/tree/master/data/departamentos/DEPARTAMENTOS.shp"; The file doesn't seem to exist.
In addition: Warning message:
In CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet,  :
  GDAL Error 4: Failed to read GeoJSON data

```
  departamento <- read_sf("https://github.com/jincio/COVID_19_PERU/tree/master/data/departamentos/DEPARTAMENTOS.shp") %>%
    select(Departamento = DEPARTAMEN, geometry)
  data2 = import("reportes_minsa.xlsx", sheet=2)
  data3 = data2 %>%
    filter(Fecha == max(data2$Fecha)) %>%
    dplyr::rename(Departamento = REGION) %>%
    dplyr::group_by(Departamento) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(casos = sum(Positivos))
  m1 = departamento %>%
    left_join(data3, by="Departamento") %>%
    mutate(casos = replace_na(casos,0),
           casos=as.factor(casos),
           label = paste0(Departamento, ": ", casos))%>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_sf(aes(fill = casos), size = 0.05, color = "grey40") +
    # colorRampPalette crea una paleta de colores del tamaño de factor(casos) -1
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey80", colorRampPalette(colors = c("#FFF5F0","#FB6A4A", "#67000D"))(length(unique(data3$casos)-1)))) +
    ggrepel::geom_label_repel(
      aes(label = label, geometry = geometry),
      stat = "sf_coordinates", 
      size = 2.3,
      min.segment.length = 0
    )+
    scale_x_discrete()+
    theme_bw()+
    theme(legend.position = "none",
          axis.title = element_blank())
```

Comment: git clone to a locat directory, then `departamento <- read_sf('~/peru_covid/COVID_19_PERU/data/departamentos/DEPARTAMENTOS.shp')` gives `> str(departamento)
Classes ‘sf’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 25 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ IDDPTO    : chr  "01" "02" "03" "04" ...
 $ DEPARTAMEN: chr  "AMAZONAS"`  & etc so the difficulty is in trying to hard code the url into git, as I get the same error as you. Right click on Download at `data/departamentos` shows `raw` rather than `blob` or `tree` but more research to do to get right incantation. Good question.

Comment: @Chris Trank you , but now I get this error message: Error: Cannot open "~/peru_covid/COVID_19_PERU/data/departamentos/DEPARTAMENTOS.shp"; The file doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: first your have to git clone to have a local directory tree. so I made a directory, peru_covid, went into it and did `chris@jacie:~/peru_covid$ git clone https://github.com/jincio/COVID_19_PERU.git
Cloning into 'COVID_19_PERU'...`, did you do that part yet? What OS and do you have git installed? and you may find, going forward that it is better to have the local git that you can update as `jincio` updates. we'll both learn git better in the process.

Comment: @Chris No , I have not installed git. Is this git? [https://git-scm.com/download/win]. I have windows 10 Home x64 bits.So how can I clone git to have a local directory? . Sure, is nice to learn together :)

Comment: Yes, your git link is what you want. Additionally, as regards `rio` [what file types rio recognizes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rio/vignettes/rio.html) which says `any format that is not supported by rio but that has a known R implementation will produce an informative error message pointing to a package and import or export function. Unrecognized formats will yield a simple “Unrecognized file format” error.` Basically `rio` doesn't know what a .shp file is.